# navigator.onLine inconsistant

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, navigator

Building a PWA and using the `navigator.onLine` property to determine if the application is online.  At the moment my focus is on Google Chrome at the moment, since it is the environment in which this app is used.

The MDN Docs state that there is inconsistency across browsers and to be wary of using it, which I understand, however I am experiencing a funny quirk that someone might be able to shed some light on.

If I run the command/line `navigator.onLine` in Google Chrome's dev console on any tab, I get true, which is good, but if I run the same thing in my App's tab, I always get false!

I've done all the checks to make sure that the "offline" is unchecked in the dev tool and all sorts, but for some bizzare reason it keeps returning false.

This PWA is built on Angular(-CLI) 6, and the tab I am trying this on is the built (`ng build`) version and not the *serve* version.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(good old Rubber-ducky Theory...)

Okay, seems **switching it on and off again** (Google Chrome's Inspector tool - network tab) seems to have fixed it, even after a refresh.

[image: Google Chrome's Inspector tool (Network Tab)]

Must have been a bug in the 73.0.3683.103 version.